# How to force delete directory backed by Gluster that will not delete even when using -r option

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glusterfs

Hi trying to delete a directory and no mater what I try I get: `rm: cannot remove 'wont_delete/delete': Directory not empty`

I'm running `sudo rm -vr wont_delete/`

The directory is on gluster fs.

Edit: Also tried `sudo rm -vrf wont_delete/`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `rm` with the options `r` and `f`

```
rm -rf wont_delete/
```

-r, -R, --recursive
remove directories and their contents recursively

-f, --force
ignore nonexistent files, never prompt

**UPDATE**

Reference: [**Unable to remove directory from GlusterFS volume mount point , Why ?**](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1264803), this solution is verified by Red Hat

### Issue

- Unable to remove directory from GlusterFS volume mount point
- Why some files and directories are missing from GlusterFS volume mountpoint but they are available in bricks?
- Unable to delete folders in gluster
- Cannot remove directory (rm -rf)

```
rmdir: failed to remove `testdir`': Directory not empty"
```

### Logs

```
W [client-rpc-fops.c:695:client3_3_rmdir_cbk] 0-volname-client-0: remote operation failed: Directory not empty

W [client-rpc-fops.c:695:client3_3_rmdir_cbk] 0-volname-client-1: remote operation failed: Directory not empty
```

### Resolution

Upgrade the cluster to Red Hat Gluster storage 3.2

### Root Cause

This can happen due to multiple issues. But the main reason is due to a stale directory or stale `link_to_file` exists in any of the brick of the volume.

### Diagnostic Steps

```
rmdir: failed to remove `testdir`': Directory not empty"
```

- Check all the bricks for this directory , here for example `testdir` and see if this directory is empty or not in all the bricks.
- Most probably this directory will be having some files and directories in some of the bricks.
- Remove `gfidlink` to this Directory or file from .glusterfs directory.
- **Important Note** Perform delete only when data inside this directory is not important .

There is another reference [**How to remove a directory from a gluster volume when rmdir unexpectedly fails with "directory not empty"**](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1264803), verified by Red Hat

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Can I manually remove the folder from the actual brick?